# How to append colon to EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to append colon to `EditText`. I am searching how to append but `EditText.append(str)` 
its append only string or any character.

I am using `phone_number.append(";");`

But its not updated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: append will definitely work even if for colon,can you place your code snippet where you passing the text and appending the text.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
    phone_number.setText("");
phone_number.setText(numb + ";");
```

It was work for me..

Answer (score 0):

May seem a bit of a hack, but if you use

```
String temp = phone_number.getText();
temp = temp + ";";
phone_number.setText(temp);
```

or some more efficient way of coding it (e.g. StringBuilder), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this works perfect.

```
phone_number.setText(phone_number.getText().toString()+";");
```

Before that you check EditText phone_number is not null.